# Can we ask for an intuitive explanation on Machine Learning/Deep Learning topics?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask for an intuitive explanation of models, algorithms, and topics related to Machine Learning/Deep Learning topics?

Like -  **Intuitive Explanation of "AutoEncoders" or "Optimizers" etc..?**

Comment: I doubt that there are any principled objections to asking for explanations at any of several different levels. The practice is how far that is possible. A personal rule of thumb is that _intuitive_ usually translates as _familiar_. "The user interface you will find to be intuitive" == "... once it has become familiar to you".  We've all (well, almost all) been caught one way or another, by someone not seeing what we regard as obvious -- or more painfully by not seeing what others regard as obvious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

We have lots of questions like that.  Take a look at what exists under our [intuition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition) tag.  If you want, you can [search on both `[intuition]` and `[machine-learning]`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition+machine-learning).

Comment: Good *gravy!* I never noticed we had an intuition tag!

Comment: 557 questions and counting, @Alexis. See you at Thanksgiving!